# JMeter not running in ANT

Tags: jenkins, ant, jmeter, build.xml

I am struggling to understand the issue but unable to figure out. Here is my issue.

I have `ANT_HOME`, `JMeter` and `Jenkins` which are all in `C: drive`. When I run my project .jmx file using ant it works fine. Here I have put all my ANT configuration under \extras folder. However if i copy the same set up into Jenkins then below jmeter element in `build.xml` is not being executed.

```html
        <jmeter
            jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
            testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
            resultlog="${logpath}/${test}.xml">
        <!--
            <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
            <jmeterarg value="-qextra.properties"/>
        -->
            <!-- Force suitable defaults -->
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
            <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
        </jmeter>
    </target>
```

Please find more details of the location

`ANT_HOME = C:\apache-ant-1.9.11
ANT in JMeter path (this is running perfectly) = C:\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras
ANT in Jenkins path (issue) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras`

Below is the full build.xml snippet which is not working.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
    
       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    
   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->
<project name="ant-jmeter" default="all">
    <description>

        Sample build file for use with ant-jmeter.jar
        See http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php

    To run a test and create the output report:
        ant -Dtest=script

    To run a test only:
        ant -Dtest=script run

    To run report on existing test output
        ant -Dtest=script report

    The "script" parameter is the name of the script without the .jmx suffix.

    Additional options:
        -Dshow-data=y - include response data in Failure Details
        -Dtestpath=xyz - path to test file(s) (default user.dir).
                         N.B. Ant interprets relative paths against the build file
        -Djmeter.home=.. - C:/Jmeter/apache-jmeter-4.0
        -Dreport.title="My Report" - title for html report (default is 'Load Test Results')
    </description>
    
 <property name="logdir" value="log"/>
 <property name="logpath" value="${user.dir}/${logdir}"/>
    <property name="testpath" value="${user.dir}"/>
    <property name="jmeter.home" value="${basedir}"/>
    <property name="report.title" value="Load Test Results"/>
    
    <!-- Name of test (without .jmx) -->
    <property name="test" value="MockTrading"/>
    
    <!-- Should report include response data for failures? -->
    <property name="show-data" value="n"/>

    <property name="format" value="2.1"/>
    
    <condition property="style_version" value="_21">
        <equals arg1="${format}" arg2="2.1"/>
    </condition>

    <condition property="funcMode">
        <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
    </condition>
    
    <condition property="funcMode" value="false">
      <not>
        <equals arg1="${show-data}" arg2="y"/>
      </not>
    </condition>

    <!-- Allow jar to be picked up locally -->
    <path id="jmeter.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}">
          <include name="ant-jmeter*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef
        name="jmeter"
        classpathref="jmeter.classpath"
        classname="org.programmerplanet.ant.taskdefs.jmeter.JMeterTask"/>
    
    <target name="all" depends="run,report"/>

    <target name="run">
        <echo>funcMode = ${funcMode}</echo>  
        <delete file="${logpath}/${test}.html"/>
        <jmeter
            jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
            testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
            resultlog="${logpath}/${test}.xml">
   <!--
            <jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
            <jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
            <jmeterarg value="-qextra.properties"/>
        -->
            <!-- Force suitable defaults -->
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format" value="xml"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results" value="all"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes" value="true"/>
            <property name="file_format.testlog" value="${format}"/>
            <property name="jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error" value="${funcMode}"/>
        </jmeter>
    </target>

    <property name="lib.dir" value="${jmeter.home}/lib"/>

    <!-- Use xalan copy from JMeter lib directory to ensure consistent processing with Java 1.4+ -->
    <path id="xslt.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="xalan*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="serializer*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="report" depends="xslt-report,copy-images">
        <echo>Report generated at ${report.datestamp}</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="xslt-report" depends="_message_xalan">
        <tstamp><format property="report.datestamp" pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"/></tstamp>
        <xslt
            classpathref="xslt.classpath"
            force="true"
            in="${logpath}/${test}.xml"
            out="${logpath}/${test}.html"
            style="${basedir}/jmeter-results-detail-report${style_version}.xsl">
            <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
            <param name="titleReport" expression="${report.title}"/>
            <param name="dateReport" expression="${report.datestamp}"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <!-- Copy report images if needed -->
    <target name="copy-images" depends="verify-images" unless="samepath">
        <copy file="${basedir}/expand.png" tofile="${logpath}/expand.png"/>
        <copy file="${basedir}/collapse.png" tofile="${logpath}/collapse.png"/>
    </target>

    <target name="verify-images">
        <condition property="samepath">
                <equals arg1="${testpath}" arg2="${basedir}" />
        </condition>
    </target>

    <!-- Check that the xalan libraries are present -->
    <condition property="xalan.present">
          <and>
              <!-- No need to check all jars; just check a few -->
            <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
            <available classpathref="xslt.classpath" classname="org.apache.xml.serializer.ExtendedContentHandler"/>
          </and>
    </condition>

    <target name="_message_xalan" unless="xalan.present">
          <echo>Cannot find all xalan and/or serialiser jars</echo>
        <echo>The XSLT formatting may not work correctly.</echo>
        <echo>Check you have xalan and serializer jars in ${lib.dir}</echo>
    </target>


</project>
```

Below is the output

```html
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras>ant
Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\build.xml

run:
     [echo] funcMode = false
   [delete] Deleting: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\log\MockTrading.html
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\MockTrading.jmx ==> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\log\MockTrading.xml

_message_xalan:

xslt-report:
     [xslt] Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\log\MockTrading.xml to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\log\MockTrading.html
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JMeter_Run\apache-jmeter-4.0\extras\jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I spotted out the issue. Here is the solution I found.

Jenkins will look after build.xml in the workspace and not any sub folders. The same path should be configured in the Jenkins->Job->Configure->ANT build path

All supporting lib and bin folder should be in workspace without creating any sub folder